# Error Replace Query in Postgis

Tags: sql, post, postgis

i have code like this

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(replace( koordinat, ',', ' '))');
```

when i ran this query. showing error like this ? how to solve this probem..

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'))'"
```

LINE 1: ...ECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(replace( koordinat, ',', ' '))');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must build a string using the concatenate operator `||`:

```
'POINT('|| replace( koordinat, ',', ' ')  ||')'
```

Furthermore is recommended to set the SRID of the output geometry by passing a [SRID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) as second parameter to the function ST_GeomFromText(). Assuming you have lon/lat coordinates, you will use 4326 as SRID:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT('||replace( koordinat, ',', ' ') ||  ')', 4326) 
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT('||replace( '-71.064544,42.28787', ',', ' ')||')') -> i found my problem thx